# How can I create the Table and insert the json data by using JAVA in CQL?

Tags: java, json, cassandra, cql

I am the new learner in CQL.
I am using the docker env to run the Cassandra.

In previous, I have the two tables(restaurants and Inspection) with inserted the data by `csv`  and the following setting:

[image]

Since `join` method are not supported in CQL, I need to re-insert the joined data set(JSON) to a new table(call InspectionrestaurantNY).

Therefore, I tried to create the InspectionrestaurantNY table:
[image]

Then, I have the `jav` which help me to install the `json` file.
But I got the error, and I don't know what table(InspectionrestaurantNY)  setting should I create to insert the `json` data.

I ran the `java -jar JSonFile2Cassandra.jar -host 192.168.99.101 -port 3000 -keyspace restaurantsNY -columnFamily InspectionsRestaurants -file InspectionsRestaurantsNY.json`, it shown the following error:

[image]

And, my `json` file is stored as like this:
[image][image][image][image]

What table setting should I build up first to insert the JSON data?

How to solve the JAVA error?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please consider pasting actual code or error log instead of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using wrong table name when running jar to insert JSON. The command you shared is

> java -jar JSonFile2Cassandra.jar -host 192.168.99.101 -port 3000
>   -keyspace restaurantsNY -columnFamily InspectionsRestaurants -file InspectionsRestaurantsNY.json

Shouldnt it be

> java -jar JSonFile2Cassandra.jar -host 192.168.99.101 -port 3000
>   -keyspace restaurantsNY -columnFamily InspectionsRestaurantsNY -file InspectionsRestaurantsNY.json

i.e use correct table name **InspectionsRestaurantsNY** for -columnFamily argument in above command.

Also its always better not to use camel case convention as CQL identifier names are case-insensitive. If you really really want case sensitive names then you should enclose names in double quotes. If double quotes are not used then Cassandra will convert names with mixed case to lower case. But in above query I dont think that is cause of error. I think its due to wrong column family name.

Check here for mixed cases names
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/ucase-lcase_r.html

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Cassandra is case sensitive when handling with names, you created it with camel case `InspectionsRestaurantsNY`, but you are trying to insert it in lower case `inspectionsrestaurantsny`.

Having the names in lowercase is preferred, as when you use cqlsh, you will need to enclose the name in double quotes if there are capital letters.

Comment: what does it mean? The java error is because of the camel case on name of InspectionsRestaurantsNY ?

Comment: when i running the `desc inspectionsrestaurantny` or `desc InspectionsRestaurantsNY` are also can return the result in cqlsh

Comment: the java error is because the query to do the insert is using lowercase for the table name

Comment: one question, how are you indicating that you'll be using the keyspace `restaurantsNY` ? it may work if you include in the insert query `restaurantsNY.InspectionsRestaurantsNY`